# proper word or phrase for 'already eaten or drank by other person/animal'

Tags: phrases

Is there a single word or a short phrase to better describe a consumable item (e.g. drink or food) that has already been nibbled or sipped at? The relevance of this word or phrase would be in a situation where someone has eaten or drank some food such that it cannot be given to someone else, due to, for example, saliva.

Comment: This question should be moved to ELL.

Comment: "defiled by contact with mouth/ spittle:" It's more a cultural thing. Some cultures do and many don't make a distinction between food or drink that has been "touched" (i.e., somewhat used) by someone or some animal. I don't think there's a word for that concept in the English language.

Comment: Some dictionaries translate the idea into English as 'leavings' for want of a better fitting word.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Someone went on a downvote spree through this thread, I have no idea why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a term for something that is tainted with another's saliva?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/is-there-a-term-for-something-that-is-tainted-with-anothers-saliva). Also [Word for “food only partially eaten”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/), though I'm supposing OP is trying to translate [***jutha***](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/308951/jutha), a concept peculiar to Hinduism.

Comment: tainted, contaminated, cooties ...

Comment: Children, seeking to reserve food for themselves, may claim *dibs* by licking the item.

Answer (score 0):

Americans don't usually put food back on a common plate after eating part of it, so this doesn't come up enough to warrant a special word for it. If I saw a sandwich with a bite taken out of it, I'd call it *partially-eaten*.

Answer (score -1):

The term that I think is most relevant here is

> [Leftovers](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=leftovers%20define)

The word on it's own doesn't necessarily denote food that is no longer fit for consumption, however, you could add in an adjective to do this;

> Dirty leftovers

This could be used as follows in the situation you described:

> Lewis wanted some cake, but Jiten only left him some grubby leftovers.

In a formal setting however, like on an incident report or food safety course, the correct word would be;

> [Contaminated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contaminated)

For example:

> It is not advisable to eat any food that may have been contaminated by animal contact.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the question correctly, I would use the term "pregurgitated." However, ingurgitate may more closely fit the food/beverage distinction.

Comment: I think you mean 'regurgitated', as 'pregurgitated' is not a recognised word. However I don't think this word would be correct in the situation because to regurgitate something would be to par-digest it and vomit it back up and that's definitely not what the question is implying xD I guess pregurgitated and ingurgitate may mean to eat some food, but then the subject is the consumed good, and not what is left of the consumed good.