# What do you call the final sip of water in a bottle (with all the saliva)?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was on a trip a while ago a friend had a word for the final bit of water in a bottle. The point of the word was to emphasize the (purported) high percentage of saliva in the final sip in a bottle. The word was used in situations where multiple people had drunk from the same bottle before the final sip.

I have forgotten the exact noun, but it sounded like **/ɣɝʃlɛ/** to me. I'm fairly sure it wasn't a word in original English - it may have been borrowed from Hebrew or Arabic.

I found a [reddit page](http://www.reddit.com/r/germany/comments/1a3k1z/german_saying_for_the_last_sip_of_beer/) with a similar question for German, where one user mentions "Spuckschluck", but it's not the word I remember.

Comment: Related (more broad): [Is there a term for something that is tainted with another's saliva?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/is-there-a-term-for-something-that-is-tainted-with-anothers-saliva)

Answer (score 6):

The word I am aware of is [*backwash* (ODO)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backwash#backwash__7). Although it doesn't specifically refer to the last sip, it is what the last sip will be made of.

> The liquid that flows back into a bottle, glass, etc. after someone has taken a drink, assumed to contain that person’s saliva

So I would call it the "backwash sip".

Answer (score 4):

The closest word I can think of for "the nasty stuff left at the bottom of a bottle after it's been drained" is "***dregs***".

However, that word usually refers to *sediment* of some sort, the settling out or precipitation of something that was in the solution to begin with, like the [*lees*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/lees?showCookiePolicy=true) (dead yeast, basically) in an old bottle of wine.

It doesn't usually refer to something introduced from external sources, so  I personally wouldn't use it to refer to the [spittle](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/spittle?showCookiePolicy=true) in the bottom of a communal bottle.

Answer (score 0):

Always called it the "pissline" at parties in my youth. It's slang but I really dont know how it came about.